# is there a function that lets me look at the next char?

Tags: c, function

is there a function in c that lets me look at the next char in an array?  Also where could I find this information on my own, I tried Google and looking for existing threads on this site.

I am trying to pull numbers from a line, and store those numbers.  So I want to do something like

if(c = a number and c "next character" is not a number){value is = value*10+c-'0', store number}

Comment: You don't need a function to access members of an array.  Can you post some code to clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: We'd need some more info, you access an array by index, so you'd just access that index directly, e.g. myArray[i+1] . Is that what you're asking about ?

Comment: @nos ok edited the question to give a little more info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a method to do this:

```
char next_char(char *array, int i, int size){
    return (++i) < size ? array[i] : '\0';
}
```

EDIT:  After reading your question something like this may be reasonable.

```
if(isdigit(array[i]) && !isdigit(next_char(array,i,size)){
    ..
}
```

A better solution would be a for loop:

```
int val = 0;
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if(isdigit(i)){
        val = 10 * val + array[i] - '0';
    }else{
        // Store the value
        val = 0;            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If the current character is `array[i]`, the next character is `array[i+1]`.

Answer (score 0):

To get a char from a char  array, you just use:

```
array[i]
```

where is is an index.

If you want to read every char, you can use a loop:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++)
{
  char cur = array[i];
}
```

You could also increment a pointer.